# count occurrences of items in an array from an nested items in an array of objects javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, object, find-occurrences

I have this array of dates.

```
const dateArray = ["7/12/2021","7/13/2021","7/14/2021","7/15/2021"]
```

and I am trying to see if any of these dates appear inside my other array of array of objects, those dates will match something inside the objects.

```
const data = [ 
      [ { id: 1, date: "7/13/2021" }, { id:2, date: "7/15/2021" } ],
      [ { id: 1, date: "7/14/2021" }, { id:2, date: "7/15/2021" } ],
]
```

so if date doesn't match I want to return 0 for that date. something like this

```
const result = [
     [0, 1, 0, 1],
     [0, 0, 1, 1]
]
```

I tried something like this.....

```
var getResult = (dateArray, data) => {
    const result = []
    let index = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < dateArray.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
            let count = 0
            if (dateArray[i] === data[j][index].date) {
                count++
                index++
                if (index === data[i].length) {
                    return
                }
            }
            result.push(count)
        }
    }
    console.log(result)
}
```

but it doesn't work of course....
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is the result the expected output for the example ``data``? Can you explain more

Comment: so to get this clear first check if the date in the data array exists in the ```dateArray``` array then if it exists write 1 in the result array and if it doesn't exist write 0 in the result array?

Comment: yes the result is the expected output, and it's supposed to count the occurences of date from dateArray inside data, I am sorry I am not clear, but is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```js
const dateArray = ["7/12/2021", "7/13/2021", "7/14/2021", "7/15/2021"];

const data = [
  [{
    id: 1,
    date: "7/13/2021"
  }, {
    id: 2,
    date: "7/15/2021"
  }],
  [{
    id: 1,
    date: "7/14/2021"
  }, {
    id: 2,
    date: "7/15/2021"
  }],
];

const result = data.map(item => {

  const resArr = (new Array(dateArray.length)).fill(0);
  item.forEach(entity => {
    const index = dateArray.findIndex(dateItem => dateItem == entity.date);
    if (index >= 0) {
      resArr[index]++;
    }
  });
  return resArr;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I am sorry but what does 
```
(new Array(dateArray.length)).fill(0);
``` do? and thank you for the quick answer!

Comment: That creates an array with length of `dateArray` and fills it with 0s. I.e., let's say dateArray has a length of 4, it creates this array `[0, 0, 0, 0]`

Answer (score 2):

```js
const 
  dateArray = ["7/12/2021","7/13/2021","7/14/2021","7/15/2021"],
  data = [ 
    [ { id: 1, date: "7/13/2021" }, { id:2, date: "7/15/2021" } ],
    [ { id: 1, date: "7/14/2021" }, { id:2, date: "7/15/2021" } ],
  ];

// iterate over data
const result = data.map(arr => {
  // get occurences count of current array dates
  const occurences = arr.reduce((map, {date}) => 
    map.set(date, (map.get(data) || 0) + 1)
  , new Map);
  // return list of occurences for dateArray elements
  return dateArray.map(date => occurences.get(date) || 0);
}, []);

console.log(result);
```